# Rust IO when in --release mode incrediably fast, but writing time is horriably slow

Tags: file, rust, io

Tell me if I need to provide more info. So, My program can eat a 75 gig .bin file in no time at all, but writing those files takes a long time, I wonder if it is because even though they are .bin files, i can still read them as text. Here is my writing to Disk code:

```rust
println!("\nWriting to Disk...\n");
fs::create_dir(Path::new(&name_path)).unwrap();
let mut layer_path = format!("quirkscape/saves/{}/world.bin", name.trim());
let mut world_file = File::create(layer_path).expect("Uh Oh");
for k in data {
    write!(world_file, "{}", k).unwrap();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [`BufWriter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufWriter.html) so that any writes are done in batches.

> It can be excessively inefficient to work directly with something that implements `Write`. For example, every call to `write` on `TcpStream` results in a system call. A `BufWriter<W>` keeps an in-memory buffer of data and writes it to an underlying writer in large, infrequent batches.

```
let mut world_file = BufWriter::new(File::create(layer_path).expect("Uh Oh"));
            
for k in data {
    write!(world_file, "{}", k).unwrap();
}
```

Comment: It does not matter if `k` is small/large. What matters is if `k` makes many small and frequent write operations. The `write!` macro will expand into separate write calls for each formatting element (Ex: `"{}"` or `"{:?}"`) so the number of writes can increase quickly when you also consider that each implementation of `Debug` or `Display` also does the same thing. `BufWriter` will handle buffering writes for you and send them periodically in chunks.

Comment: @Locke you're right! I've removed the wording.

Comment: WOW! that sped it up insanely, unoptimized takes around 6 seconds, instead of 2 - 3 minutes!